# How do you change the URL alias of a contact form?

Tags: 8, path-aliases

Sounds simple enough, right? I can't find it anywhere. My contact form's path remains:

```
/contact/contact_us
```

And I have no idea where to change this. I have checked under the form settings at:

```
/admin/structure/contact/manage/contact_us
```

Which leads me to believe that perhaps all contact forms are in the structure:

```
/contact/[FORM_SYSTEM_NAME]
```

Is that the case or is it possible to change it?

**UPDATE**

What I really want is a simple ALIAS field per contact form, so I can set the url alias myself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I went under Configuration --> URL Aliases, and added a new alias for /contact-us that points to /contact/contact_us

I expected the result to be that anyone typing in /contact-us would end up at /contact/contact_us, but instead the opposite is happening. Anyone typing in /contact/contact_us is now redirected to /contact-us and the page is shown there.

This is a little different from how Drupal 7 works, but this is the answer I needed.

Comment: Actually the path is Configuration->Search And Metadata->Url aliases

Answer (score 2):

You can, in fact, change it.
To do that you should use a route subscriber service class.

Such class will implement the alterRoutes method which will give you the ability to change the path of the contact page.

*I'll update with code examples when I'll be near my computer.*

Comment: Actually, you can't change the route for just one contact form since they all use the same route. What you can do is register a new route that will display a contact form, sure. But I don't think that's the point, you don't want to do that for every contact form you're adding. You also don't register a custom route for every node you create. You just create aliases.

Comment: I thought that the OP wanted to change to routes for all contact forms. Are you sure that the OP wants to change the route of only a single form?

Comment: What I want is a URL Alias field per contact form.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the case. You can't *change* that.

That said, you can always add aliases and use whatever path you want as an alias for /contact/form-id. It's not available directly in the contact form (there's an issue open for that, though) but you have to manually add it from the alias overview page at `admin/config/search/path`.

Comment: Wait, you can't alias it with something like Pathauto?

Comment: Pathauto currently supports content entities. So you can create aliases, but only manually and only from the global alias management page. As I said, there's an issue in the core issue queue to add an alias field to the contact form, would be relatively easy to implement but hasn't happened yet.